# addMethod error on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

i have this script to validate the filesize when you upload a file:

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    // param = size (en bytes) 
    // element = element to validate (<input>)
    // value = value of the element (file name)
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});
```

and i keep getting this error only in IE9:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
```

IE9 Debug says the error is in this line:

```
return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, IE9 doesn't have support for file API. You'll need to do it server-side or use a plugin.

Comment: any idea of what plugin could i use to make it work in all browsers?

Comment: Try with [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), is the most widely used. WordPress uses this plugin.